# HTML Divs making stuff go down?

Tags: html

EDIT: FIXED I CHANGED IT TO

this is my code

```
Account Type: <div id="accounttype" class=inline-block"><strong><?=$_SESSION['accounttype']?></strong></div>
```

Now on my site it shows like this

```
account type:
personal
```

but without the div it shows like this

```
account type: personal
```

how can i make it WITH the div show like this

```
account type: personal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Account Type: <div id="accounttype" style="display:inline-block"><strong><?=$_SESSION['accounttype']?></strong></div>
```

Or more appropriately:

```
Account Type: <span id="accounttype"><strong><?=$_SESSION['accounttype']?></strong></span>
```

Comment: I said i fixed it lol but ill check you any way but i will in 9 minutes cause it says i have to in 9 minutes -.-

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `Account Type:` in a div with style="float:left"

Answer (score 0):

Try this;
`Account Type: <div id="accounttype" class="inline-block"><strong><?=$_SESSION['accounttype']?></strong></div`

just you should use " after class=